# EditText not receiving TAB key events - stock soft vk

Tags: android, listview, tabs, android-edittext, keyevent

My app has a `ListView` and an `EditText` sitting below it. For some reason, the TAB key doesn't trigger the `onKeyListener`. All other keys I'm handling (DEL, ENTER, DPAD_UP/DOWN/CENTER) are received just fine. I added a breakpoint in `dispatchKeyEvent`, again no luck receiving TAB events.

My app previously had a large `TextView` for displaying text and during this time, TAB events were received fine. The `ListView` has now replaced the `TextView`.

I'm completely mystified as to why the TAB event is no longer being received. This is on a stock Xoom, running ICS 4.0.4 & stock N1, with 2.3.6.

I've compared my current code against the version using a `TextView` and much of the code is just to handle the `ListView` in the place of the `TextView`. Apart from `nextFocusLeft` and `nextFocusRight` attributes, nothing else has changed for the EditText.

Edit: I just tried with Go Keyboard and Hacker's Keyboard and TAB is received fine. It appears this is with just some virtual keyboards

Answer (score 0):

I think I may see the problem.  Looking at the source for ListView.java, there is a mechanism to consume key events that shift focus within a list item.  Check out the comments preceding this method as well as the block of comments in the middle of the method.

```
/**
 * To avoid horizontal focus searches changing the selected item, we
 * manually focus search within the selected item (as applicable), and
 * prevent focus from jumping to something within another item.
 * @param direction one of {View.FOCUS_LEFT, View.FOCUS_RIGHT}
 * @return Whether this consumes the key event.
 */
private boolean handleHorizontalFocusWithinListItem(int direction) {
    if (direction != View.FOCUS_LEFT && direction != View.FOCUS_RIGHT)  {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("direction must be one of"
                + " {View.FOCUS_LEFT, View.FOCUS_RIGHT}");
    }

    final int numChildren = getChildCount();
    if (mItemsCanFocus && numChildren > 0 && mSelectedPosition != INVALID_POSITION) {
        final View selectedView = getSelectedView();
        if (selectedView != null && selectedView.hasFocus() &&
                selectedView instanceof ViewGroup) {

            final View currentFocus = selectedView.findFocus();
            final View nextFocus = FocusFinder.getInstance().findNextFocus(
                    (ViewGroup) selectedView, currentFocus, direction);
            if (nextFocus != null) {
                // do the math to get interesting rect in next focus' coordinates
                currentFocus.getFocusedRect(mTempRect);
                offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(currentFocus, mTempRect);
                offsetRectIntoDescendantCoords(nextFocus, mTempRect);
                if (nextFocus.requestFocus(direction, mTempRect)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            // we are blocking the key from being handled (by returning true)
            // if the global result is going to be some other view within this
            // list.  this is to acheive the overall goal of having
            // horizontal d-pad navigation remain in the current item.
            final View globalNextFocus = FocusFinder.getInstance().findNextFocus(
                    (ViewGroup) getRootView(), currentFocus, direction);
            if (globalNextFocus != null) {
                return isViewAncestorOf(globalNextFocus, this);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Are there multiple focusable items within a single list element?  If so, this code will consume the tab key.  If that is the case, then you may want to make some of the items unfocusable or consider another design option.

Comment: I set up a test project to test this and unfortunately it didn't work. The edittext always has focus so it should always receive the keyevent, or at the very least, it should be caught in dispatchKeyEvent. This works fine with Hackers Keyboard but not the stock one. I've uploaded the test project here http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78755665/Test.zip Everything is set to be non-focusable in the listview

Comment: When I run it on my Samsung Galaxy SII Epic 4G, the soft keyboard doesn't even show a tab key.

Comment: The emulator keyboard doesn't have a tab key either.

Comment: Suggestion, try .setKeyListener() instead of setOnKeyListener() and listen for the key press.

Comment: setKeyListener isn't appropriate for this if the documentation is anything to go by